# What is the Xcode equivalent to Eclipse's "Insert Best Guessed Arguments"?

Tags: xcode, eclipse, preferences

In eclipse you can go to Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist and choose to autofill arguments with a best guess rather than the parameter names.  Is there a similar preference in Xcode?

Comment: I can only hope there isn't. I can't even imagine the endless possibilities for errors like `return [self autorelease];` instead of `return [tmp autorelease];`...

Comment: It doesn't make any sense for it to try to guess which object you're sending a message to.  The idea would be instead of `[randomArray addObject:(NSObject)` it would fill `(NSObject)` with the best guessed object that you're going to add to the array, most likely the one you were just previously creating or modifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode will automatically attempt to auto-fill code for you. For example, if you are writing something that takes an NSString argument, it will search through your available strings when you start typing a letter. So accept it, just hit `<return>`.

If though, you mean that you want the auto-inserted code to not display the `doThis:<NSString*>` `andThat:<NSString*>` and instead try to autofill those with possible NSStrings, then no. Xcode does not have  preference.

Comment: The default in eclipse does exactly what you're talking about, and the new preference replaces what's automatically inserted (the name of the parameter, or in Xcode's case the type of argument) with a best guess.

Comment: Hmm, my formatting was wrong. Anyway, @JuJoDi, as seen from my last paragraph, Xcode will not automatically fill possible arguments. There is no preference.